# Highlight data that match with data from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, regex

I have two tabs in a Spreadsheet. Both are having a list of data. I want to highlight cells in one tab that match with cells from another tab.

For example:

Tab 1

```
Column 1
ABC
XYZ
PQR
DEF
```

Tab 2

```
Column 1
DEF
PQR
```

Here, I want DEF and PQR to get highlighted in Tab 1 data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:A")))
```

[image: 0]